# Laravel 6 Pull a package in through Composer (development/latest version dev-master)

Tags: laravel, package, composer-php

I am trying to install Kyslik/column-sortable with this documentation

https://packagist.org/packages/kyslik/column-sortable

It says I have to Pull this package in through Composer (development/latest version dev-master)

```
{
    "require": {
        "kyslik/column-sortable": "^6.0"
    }
}
```

so where exactly do I have to add this line of code? I've tried adding it to my composer.json file "require" but when I update my composer it says

```
- Installation request for kyslik/column-sortable ^6.0 -> satisfiable by kyslik/column-sortable[6.0.0, 6.1.0, 6.2.0].
```

How do I install kyslik/column-sortable? Any tips or help is appreciated

### Update 1.0

When i run the `composer require kyslik/column-sortable` command
I get the following error:

```
    Using version ^6.2 for kyslik/column-sortable
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/framework (locked at v6.14.0, required as ^5.2) is satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.14.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.48
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.47
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.46
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.45
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.43
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.42
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.41
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.40
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.39
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.45
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.44
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.43
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.42
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 5.2.41
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.40
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.39
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.0-RC1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0-beta1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 5.8.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 5.7.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 5.6.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 5.5.x-dev
    - Installation request for kyslik/column-sortable ^6.2 -> satisfiable by kyslik/column-sortable[6.2.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 5.4.x-dev
    - Installation request for laravel/tinker (locked at v2.2.0, required as ^2.0) -> satisfiable by laravel/tinker[v2.2.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 5.3.x-dev
    - kyslik/column-sortable 6.2.0 requires illuminate/database 5.8.*|^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.14.0, 5.8.x-dev, v5.8.0, v5.8.1, v5.8.10, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.13, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.16, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22, v5.8.23, v5.8.24, v5.8.25, v5.8.26, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.4, v5.8.5, v5.8.6, v5.8.7, v5.8.8, v5.8.9], illuminate/database[5.8.x-dev, 6.x-dev, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.22, v5.8.24, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.2.x-dev, v6.14.0].
    - don't install illuminate/database 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.36|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database 6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.1.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.10.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.11.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.12.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.13.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.13.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.14.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.15.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.15.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.16.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.17.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.17.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.2.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.3.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.4.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.5.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.5.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.5.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.6.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.6.1|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.6.2|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.7.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/database v6.8.0|don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^5.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.2.41, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.x-dev, 5.8.x-dev, v5.2.0, v5.2.0-beta1, v5.2.1, v5.2.10, v5.2.11, v5.2.12, v5.2.13, v5.2.14, v5.2.15, v5.2.16, v5.2.17, v5.2.18, 
5.2.33, v5.2.34, v5.2.35, v5.2.36, v5.2.37, v5.2.38, v5.2.39, v5.2.4, v5.2.40, v5.2.42, v5.2.43, v5.2.44, v5.2.45, v5.2.5, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.2.8, v5.2.9, v5.3.0, v5.3.0-RC1, v5.3.1, v5.3.10, v5.3.11, v5.3.12, v5.3.13, v5.3.14, v5.3.15, v5.3.16, v5.3.17, v5.3.18, v5.3.19, v5.3.2, v5.3.20, v5.3.21, v5.3.22, v5.3.23, v5.3.24, v5.3.25, v5.3.26, v5.3.27, v5.3.28, v5.3.29, v5.3.3, v5.3.30, v5.3.31, v5.3.4, v5.3.5, v5.3.6, v5.3.7, 
v5.3.8, v5.3.9, v5.4.0, v5.4.1, v5.4.10, v5.4.11, v5.4.12, v5.4.13, v5.4.14, v5.4.15, v5.4.16, v5.4.17, v5.4.18, v5.4.19, v5.4.2, v5.4.20, v5.4.21, v5.4.22, v5.4.23, v5.4.24, v5.4.25, v5.4.26, v5.4.27, v5.4.28, v5.4.29, v5.4.3, v5.4.30, v5.4.31, v5.4.32, v5.4.33, v5.4.34, v5.4.35, v5.4.36, v5.4.4, v5.4.5, v5.4.6, v5.4.7, v5.4.8, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.1, v5.5.10, v5.5.11, v5.5.12, v5.5.13, v5.5.14, v5.5.15, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.18, v5.5.19, v5.5.2, v5.5.20, v5.5.21, v5.5.22, v5.5.23, v5.5.24, v5.5.25, v5.5.26, v5.5.27, v5.5.28, v5.5.29, v5.5.3, v5.5.30, v5.5.31, v5.5.32, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.38, v5.5.39, v5.5.4, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.42, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.5.45, v5.5.46, v5.5.47, v5.5.48, v5.5.5, v5.5.6, v5.5.7, v5.5.8, v5.5.9, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, 
v5.6.18, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.12, v5.7.13, v5.7.14, v5.7.15, v5.7.16, v5.7.17, v5.7.18, v5.7.19, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.24, v5.7.25, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9, v5.8.0, v5.8.1, v5.8.10, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.13, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.16, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22, v5.8.23, v5.8.24, v5.8.25, v5.8.26, v5.8.27, v5.8.28, v5.8.29, v5.8.3, v5.8.30, v5.8.31, v5.8.32, v5.8.33, v5.8.34, v5.8.35, v5.8.36, v5.8.37, v5.8.4, v5.8.5, v5.8.6, v5.8.7, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: To require package with composer you should use [`composer require <dependency>`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require). Because composer update like recommended in the [doc of your dependency](https://packagist.org/packages/kyslik/column-sortable) will update all your dependencies and it's not recommanded. Try to run the `composer require kyslik/column-sortable` and add response of command if it's not work

Comment: How do you "update" your composer? Is there anything else printed to the shell, besides that single line?

Comment: When i try to run composer require kyslik/column-sortable i get a very long error message which i will post in my question as an update

Comment: Can you post your complete composer.json? The error looks a bit irritating. If you are feeling lucky, you can try `composer require kyslik/column-sortable --update-with-all-dependencies`. The flag `--update-with-all-dependencies` will also update your root dependencies (including laravel) if necessary. This can break your project if there were any breaking changes, so be careful with this.